# .load() jQuery doesn't work with chrome?

Tags: jquery

My code works prefectly on Firefox, but not on Chrome.  Is there a problem with jQuery `.load()` on Google Chrome?

Comment: It works fine, your description is very vague though, you should update your question with where you're calling it.  For example are you calling it from a `file://` path?

Comment: It's probably a problem with how you're using it.

Comment: i'm using it on a page ..ill just post a link here

Comment: it works just fine, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me - if you are running your code on your machine and not from a live website, Chrome may be disallowing the call for security reasons.

If this doesn't help, could you post what the JS console is saying?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is cross-browser - it means that it should work on every browser. but maybe it doesn't work because those reasons:

1. You are running it locally (not on server) and Chrome doesn't allow loading from local files.
2. You are valling data from ASP.net, you are using Response.Close() that close down the socket
3. Maybe chrome is caching the data, try putting $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into your exact same problem, where an jquery script wasn't working with chrome but it does work in all the other browsers.

I am yet to find a perfect solution. However I believe the problem is with chromes caching.

if you clear your cache  your script will probably succeed one time, and than stop on the next load.

I solved my issue by  adding  a a cache buster onto the image url i was checking for download.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery within a chrome extension, and have selected document-start for the script processing level, much of what you expect wont work correctly because chrome is not waiting for the onload to call ready()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("window load event");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("started processing jQueries ");
}
</script>

started processing jQueries 
window load event
```

so you can see that chrome is starting processing the script before the DOM load is complete.

The best suggestion if you need both is to not use the ready() function for chrome extensions that run-at document-start