# How do I create an if check to return a specific value of an enum in c# t?

Tags: c#, if-statement, syntax, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to conditionally return the enum value based on user permissions in a kendo grid, if the user has permission show both else show call only, im trying to do this in c# and I am stuck on the specific syntax I need for the if statement, im new to c#.

```
    <div class="left width100 margin-top10">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AddressBook>()
          .Name("grid")                                                            
           .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "left width100 kendo-grid" })                                                                                                  
           .Columns(columns => {                                                                                        
columns.Bound(p=>p.AddressBookType).EditorTemplateName("AddressBookTypeEditor").ClientTemplate("#= data.AddressBookTypeText #")});


public enum {
    Call,
    Email
   }
//permission and variable

   ViewBag.OmniEmailFeatureAccess = auth.UserHasPermission( PermissionType.AccessOmniEmail); 

                   var AddressBookType = new List<AddressBookType>();
                   if (!ViewBag)  
                     return AddressBookType(0);
```

Comment: What happens when you do `$(document).ready`

Comment: Please just read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)! It's neither!

Comment: D'oh, you are looking for a `<document>` tag in your page. There, of course, aren't any of those. there is a global variable called `document` though.

Comment: im trying to display an external html file within an html using either document.ready or window.load runs in ff and safari but not in chrome

Answer (score 4):

it's `$(document).ready(..)` not `$('document')`, also you can just use `$(function() {....});`.

Check [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)'s documentation.

Comment: `.ready()` method doesn't care about the collection. `$('foo').ready()` or `$().ready()` will work too. http://jsfiddle.net/fZk7C/, passing `document` object is just recommended.

Comment: From the linked documentation above, "_The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted._"

Comment: why does it work in safari and firefox if its a syntax issue?? and is there a work around javascript function or alternate jquery function thta I can use to satisfy all three browsers?

Comment: @codeflower The problem surely is not document ready handler. Have you inspected the Network tab of your browser?

Comment: @BlackSheep how do I inspect the network tab of chrome? I am relatively new to coding you see and this is my first major 'bug'? I totally agree it cant be the document handler (works with the other browsers)

Comment: @codeflower Do you use adblock extension in Chrome? it sometimes blocks the requests. There are many related questions on SO, one of those is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194739/load-jquery-doesnt-work-with-chrome

Comment: @BlackSheep I dont use adblock extentions on chrome but i did look through the network tab and found this No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. how do I fix it?

Comment: @codeflower Please see the linked question in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is not good, you should try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#div').load('example.html');
});
```

You can learn about .ready() in [this page](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: this is my syntax and still and go in chrome works in safari and firefox